# Pandas Concatenation no longer has sort keyword argument

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, preprocessor

In my code I am applying `pd.concat(sort=false)`. But since the package has been updated it the `sort` keyword argument is no longer available.

What are the other options to do the same.?

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to concatenate and sort or not? Your post says `sort=False` but your title seems to imply you want to sort.

Comment: I think you are being kind of mean downvoting the answer, especially for a new contributor (Welcome Shivam!), instead of trying to understand what seems a perfectly fine question to me (I may be wrong, not being around here too much myself...). I have seen a few times pandas being downgraded when updating a conda environment, and the sort keyword I guess it surprised many of us when it was introduced (we all found a warning and I had to take sometime to understand what was going on...).

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` keyword argument was introduced in version 0.23.0 (see [what’s new](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.0/whatsnew.html#concatenation-will-no-longer-sort)) in order to allow the user to control an unwanted effect (automatic sorting of indexes on non concatenating axis, only in case `join=outer`).

So it appears that during your update pandas was downgraded. Are you able to keep a version >= 0.23.0?

If not you might want to go through the related pandas issue to look for workarounds (basically you would have to *unsort* after the call).

**Edit**:

Going through the [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4588#issuecomment-366017633), the best workaround I found is:

“My workaround uses unique_everseen from the Itertools Recipes.”

```
columns = unique_everseen([column for df in dfs for column in df.columns])
df = pd.concat(dfs)[columns]
```

Comment: You are right the package was downgraded, now I have updated the package and the problem is solved.